# Model failed to serialize as JSON. Ignoring... Layer was passed non-JSON-serializable arguments

Tags: python, json, tensorflow

I'm trying to build a u-net model which has `Conv2DTranspose` layers but I get this error while training the model:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:Model failed to serialize as JSON. Ignoring... Layer tf.nn.conv2d_transpose_72 was passed non-JSON-serializable arguments. Arguments had types: {'filters': <class 'tensorflow.python.ops.resource_variable_ops.ResourceVariable'>, 'output_shape': [<class 'str'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>], 'strides': (<class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>, <class 'int'>), 'padding': <class 'str'>, 'data_format': <class 'str'>, 'dilations': <class 'NoneType'>, 'name': <class 'NoneType'>}. They cannot be serialized out when saving the model.
```

This is how I create the layer:

```
def decoder_block(input, skip_features, num_filters:int, block_name:str, dropout_rate=0.4):
      layer = Conv2DTranspose(filters=num_filters,
                                        kernel_size=5,
                                        strides=(2, 2),
                                        padding="same",
                                        use_bias=False,
                              name = f"{block_name}-upsample_conv2d_transpose_layer_1")(input)
      layer = BatchNormalization(name = f"{block_name}-upsample_batchnorm_layer_1")(layer)
      layer = Activation("relu", name = f"{block_name}-upsample_activation_layer_1")(layer)
      layer = Dropout(0.4, name = f"{block_name}-upsample_dropout_layer_1")(layer)
      layer = Concatenate(name = f"{block_name}-upsample_concatenate_layer_1")([layer, skip_features])
      layer = deconv_block(layer, num_filters, block_name)

      return layer
```

and this is how I build the model:

```
 def build_unet():

      inputs = Input(shape=input_shape, dtype=tf.float32)
      #print('\n Encoder Block \n')
      encoder_1, max_pool_1 = encoder_block(inputs, 32, "encode_block_1")
      encoder_2, max_pool_2 = encoder_block(max_pool_1, 64, "encode_block_2")
      encoder_3, max_pool_3 = encoder_block(max_pool_2, 128, "encode_block_3")
      encoder_4, max_pool_4 = encoder_block(max_pool_3, 256, "encode_block_4")
      encoder_5 = conv_block(max_pool_4, 512, "encode_block_5")
      #print('\n Decoder Block \n')
      decoder_1 = decoder_block(encoder_5, encoder_4, 256, "decode_block_1")
      decoder_2 = decoder_block(decoder_1, encoder_3, 128, "decode_block_2")
      decoder_3 = decoder_block(decoder_2, encoder_2, 64, "decode_block_3")
      decoder_4 = decoder_block(decoder_3, encoder_1, 32, "decode_block_4")

      outputs = Conv2D(2, 1, padding="same", activation="relu")(decoder_4) #the output is 2 channels, 1 for vocal and 1 for accompaniment

      model = tf.keras.models.Model(inputs, outputs, name=model_name)
      return model
```

How can I fix this issue? it doesn't let me save the model and throws an error!

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You must add 'get_config' to your code

```
def get_config(self):
    config = super().get_config()
    return config
```

It will serializable your arguments.